# Getting selected row value out of a jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

jtable get selected row value i want to make it so when u click on a row it will get the row number and put it into a variable.

```
int Test1 = 0;
```

This is in my button Listener

```
myList.remove(Test1);
```

but what do i need to find what row is selected.

any help would be grateful thanks

i used this in the end

```
     table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            sel = table.getSelectedRow();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the API documentation, [JTable has following methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection)

[getSelectedRow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow%28%29) 
[getSelectedRows()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRows%28%29) 
[getSelectedRowCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRowCount%28%29)

If your table is enabled for sorting and you want to get data from your [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) then do not forget to call [convertRowIndexToModel(int selectedRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)